# Is it possible to prove dot product by the law of cosines?

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems many people prove the geometric definition of dot product by the law of cosines. However, i think this is incomplete because the law of cosines is for a triangle, which means we can't use it when two vectors are on the same line — in other words, the angle between two vectors is 0° or 180°. Am i right?

Comment: What do you mean "prove dot product"? It is just an operation defined on vectors.

Comment: @dalastboss I want to prove why member-wise product — which is the algebraic definition — leads to the cosine of the angle between two vectors.

Comment: Then you need to prove that the geometric definition satisfies A dot (B+C) = A dot B + A dot C

Comment: @user139981 Can you elaborate on why this have something to do with what you just mentioned?

Comment: If you can prove that it's distributive, then together with the orthogonality relations of i, j, k, you have (Ai+Bj+Ck)dot(Di+Ej+Fk)=AD+BE+CF.

Comment: @user139981 I don't know why that's related to the angle between two vectors:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The law of cosines works just as well for degenerate triangles as for non-degenerate ones.